# Zebra Stripe using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to achieve the below stripe pattern, but none of the nth-child combination is working out. Any suggestion / solution to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: can you show your html code?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of _Alternate table row color using CSS?_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #7F7F7F;
}

.child:nth-child(4n+1),
.child:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: #FF0080;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The point is to see after how many `div` *elements* (`.child`) the pattern repeats, this is the first number or `4n`, then just set the first and fourth to be of the same color with the `+1` and `+4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `nth-of-type` with `n` parameter (`4n+1` and `4n+4`)

```css
.container div {
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(4n + 1),
.container div:nth-of-type(4n + 4) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>
```